# Getting error while installing application

Tags: android

I have made an application. I have used google API target 4.0 but when I run the activity ,instead of getting install it gives me error.
I have also kill the server and then start it but still I am getting same error.

```
installation error: install_failed_missing_shared_library
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting questions in capslock in the future.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about context? Are you installing to the device and it fails? Opening the app fails after it downloads? Something else? Is there any Logcat? How about posting relevant code?

Comment: If you are deploying in the emulator, the emulator needs to be created with Google Api too.

Comment: the library used is declared in the manifest file? (<uses-library ...>)

Comment: yes i have got the message on the console that apk installed.then i got the error message of Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
even my device has been opend successfully

Comment: @Chronos  yes i have created my app with google api.